# Write response to txt file in WSO2 micro integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/example2" name="Example2" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST GET">
        <inSequence>
            <clone>
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <property description="requestObject" expression="json-eval($)" name="requestObject" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <log description="logRequest" level="custom" separator=",">
                            <property expression="json-eval($)" name="logRequestObject"/>
                        </log>
                        <propertyGroup description="splitRequest">
                            <property expression="json-eval($.client)" name="JSON_CLIENT" scope="default" type="INTEGER"/>
                            <property expression="json-eval($.user)" name="JSON_USER" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                            <property expression="json-eval($.pass)" name="JSON_PASS" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        </propertyGroup>
                        <log description="logRequest" level="custom" separator=",">
                            <property expression="json-eval($.client)" name="LOG_CLIENT"/>
                            <property expression="json-eval($.user)" name="LOG_USER"/>
                            <property expression="json-eval($.pass)" name="LOG_PASS"/>
                        </log>
                        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                            <format>{&#xd;
                                "clientId":$1,&#xd;
                                "userName":"$2",&#xd;
                                "password":"$3"&#xd;
                            }</format>
                            <args>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('JSON_CLIENT')"/>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('JSON_USER')"/>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('JSON_PASS')"/>
                            </args>
                        </payloadFactory>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint key="ex2_org60"/>
                        </call>
                        <property description="responseObject" expression="json-eval($)" name="responseObject" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <log description="logResponseReturn" level="custom" separator=",">
                            <property expression="json-eval($)" name="logResponse"/>
                        </log>
                        <dbreport>
                            <connection>
                                <pool>
                                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/idempiere</url>
                                    <user>postgres</user>
                                    <password>viethoan2k1</password>
                                </pool>
                            </connection>
                            <statement>
                                <sql><![CDATA[
                                      INSERT INTO "adempiere"."sts_log_api" ("ad_client_id", "ad_org_id", "createdby", "updatedby", "request", "response", "date")
                                      VALUES (1001, 2001, 5001, 5001, ?, ?, '2023-08-17 12:00:00.000000');
                                  ]]></sql>
                                <parameter expression="get-property('requestObject')" type="VARCHAR"/>
                                <parameter expression="get-property('responseObject')" type="VARCHAR"/>
                            </statement>
                        </dbreport>
                        <propertyGroup>
                            <property expression="json-eval($.success)" name="success" scope="default" type="BOOLEAN"/>
                            <property expression="json-eval($.error.message)" name="error" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        </propertyGroup>
                        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                              <format>{&#xd;
                                  "source":"may60",&#xd;
                                "success":$1,&#xd;
                                  "error":"$2"&#xd;
                              }</format>
                            <args>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('success')"/>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('error')"/>
                            </args>
                        </payloadFactory>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </clone>
            <respond/>
            
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

and I tried to use the vfs transport but not returning a response

```xml
<log level="full"/>
<send>
    <endpoint>
        <address uri="vfs:file:///D:/log1.txt">
            <suspendOnFailure>
                <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
            </suspendOnFailure>
            <markForSuspension>
                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            </markForSuspension>
        </address>
    </endpoint>
</send>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting a response after adding to the file, add a send mediator in your out sequence.

```xml
<outSequence>
  <payloadFactory media-type="json">
      <format>{"Message": "Done"}</format>
      <args></args>
  </payloadFactory>
  <send/>
</outSequence>
```